# OpenText installation fail during deployment process SP 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-administration

I am trying to integrate the OpenText with SharePoint 2013, and all wsp's deployed on 3 out of 4 servers,
I noticed that the main server Application01 stop the Share Point Timer and FIM services,
and this is reason behind the issue:

> SettingsProvider: System.InvalidOperationException: could not create a CmdletConfiguration for CmdletName Disable-CSFeature, CmldetClass  , CmdletHelpFile C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\CONFIG\PowerShell\Help\Opentext.SharePoint.Tools.PowerShell.dll-Help.xml.
> Cannot process argument because the value of argument "implementingType" is null. Change the value of argument "implementingType" to a non-null value.
> could not create a CmdletConfiguration for CmdletName Enable-CSFeature, CmldetClass  , CmdletHelpFile C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\CONFIG\PowerShell\Help\Opentext.SharePoint.Tools.PowerShell.dll-Help.xml.
> Cannot process argument because the value of argument "implementingType" is null. Change the value of argument "implementingType" to a non-null value.
> Data Source=SPSQLCLUS;Initial Catalog="Sync DB";Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15
> at Microsoft.IdentityManagement.Samples.SettingsProvider.GetDbConnection()
> at Microsoft.IdentityManagement.Samples.SettingsProvider.Microsoft.IdentityManagement.Settings.ISettingsProvider.TryGetSetting(String name, String& value)
> at Microsoft.IdentityManagement.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.TryGetSetting(String settingName, String supportedParameters, String& value, String& unsupportedValue)
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Utilities.ExternalSettingsManager.TryGetSetting(String settingName, String supportedParameters, String& value, String& unsupportedValue)
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DatabaseConnection.InitializePrimaryStoreConnectionString()
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DatabaseConnection.get_ConnectionString()
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DatabaseConnection.Open(DataStore store)
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.TransactionAndConnectionScope..ctor(Boolean createTransaction, IsolationLevel isolationLevel, DataStore dataStore)
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.TransactionAndConnectionScope..ctor(Boolean createTransaction)
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DataAccess.RegisterService(String hostName)
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Workflow.Hosting.HostActivator.RegisterService(String hostName)
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Workflow.Hosting.HostActivator.Initialize()
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.ResourceManagementServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
> at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WindowsHostService.OnStart(String[] args)

Any suggestion to solve this.

Thanks and best regards